# Time of re-emission of a photon in Raman scattering?

Tags: scattering, raman-spectroscopy

In Raman scatering events, when a photon is absorbed by a molecule, how much time(in average for small molecules) does it stay in the Virtual Energy State caused by the absorption.

Answer (score 0):

The time can be calculated with the Uncertainty principle: 
$$\Delta t\Delta E \geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$$

Answer by: ptomato (https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/107/ptomato), Is the photon truly not absorbed in Raman scattering?, URL (version: 2017-04-13): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184439